# C# check if characters occur in a fixed order in a string

Tags: c#, string, character

I need to check if a user input resembles a parameter or not. It comes as a string (not changeable) and has to look like the following examples:

```
p123[2]      -> writable array index  
r23[12]      -> read only array index  
p3[7].5      -> writable bit in word  
r1263[13].24 -> read only bit in word  
15           -> simple value
```

The user is allowed to input any of them and my function has to distinguish them in order to call the proper function.

An idea would be to check for characters in a specific order e.g. "p[]", "r[]", "p[]." etc.

But I am not sure how to archive that without checking each single character and using multiple cases...

Any other idea of how to make sure that the user input is correct is also welcomed.

Comment: You might want a regex with capturing groups - [`^(?:(?<p>[a-zA-Z]+\d+)(?:\[(?<idx>\d+)])?(?:\.(?<inword>\d+))?|(?<simpleval>\d+))$`](https://regex101.com/r/gY4wM7/2).

Comment: The user has to input e.g. a parameter in a front end. This parameter looks like one of the above and can be an array index or a bit. 
I just have to verify that the user input matches one of the five "possibilities".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to validate user input that should come in 1 of the 5 provided formants, use a regex check:

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^(?:(?<p>[pr]\d+)(?:\[(?<idx>\d+)])?(?:\.(?<inword>\d+))?|(?<simpleval>\d+))$")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gY4wM7/3)

**Description**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of the alternation group

  - `(?<p>[pr]\d+)` - Group "p" capturing `p` or `r` and 1 or more digits after
  - `(?:\[(?<idx>\d+)])?` - an optional sequence of `[`, 1 or more digits (captured into Group "idx") and then `]`
  - `(?:\.(?<inword>\d+)‌​)?` - an optional sequence of a literal `.`, then 1 or more digits captured into Group "inword"
- `|` - or (then comes the second alternative)
- `(?<simpleval>\d+)‌​` - Group "simpleval" capturing 1 or more digits
- `)` - end of the outer grouping
- `$` - end of string.

If the `p` or `r` can be *any* ASCII letters, use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `[pr]`.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/EgSFni):

```
var strs = new List<string> { "p123[2]","r23[12]","p3[7].5","r1263[13].24","15"};
var pattern = @"^(?:(?<p>[pr]\d+)(?:\[(?<idx>\d+)])?(?:\.(?<inword>\d+))?|(?<simpleval>\d+))$";
foreach (var s in strs)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", s, Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the input match with a regex pattern :

```
1 ) Regex.IsMatch(input,@"^p\d+\[\d+\]$"); // match p123[2] 
2 ) Regex.IsMatch(input,@"^r\d+\[\d+\]$"); // match r23[12] 
3 ) Regex.IsMatch(input,@"^p\d+\[\d+\]\.\d+$"); // match p3[7].5
4 ) Regex.IsMatch(input,@"^r\d+\[\d+\]\.\d+$"); // match r1263[13].24
5 ) Regex.IsMatch(input,@"^\d+$") ;// match simple value
```

Comment: Or if you want to check all at a time: `((?<readWrite>p|r)(?<name>\d+)\[(?<index>\d+)\](\.(?<word>\d+))?)|(?<simpleValue>\d+)`. Then you just have to check the groups.

Comment: Yes depending on how the user input comes.

Comment: Thank you, helped me a lot in combination with the previous post